# Android project used to work,, now different logcat errors show off

Tags: android, api, manifest, logcat

My project was working perfectly fine , but when i've run it now ,, the following logcat appeared , i've read and practiced every single article under (Invalid API & leaked ) but nothing seems to work ,, so , where is the problem?

```
04-22 09:03:39.523: W/ActivityManager(289): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4100b980
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d6b390 that was originally bound here
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d6b390 that was originally bound here
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 09:03:39.543: E/ActivityThread(602):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602): null
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d6b390 that was originally bound here
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 09:03:39.613: E/StrictMode(602):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-22 09:03:39.653: W/ActivityManager(289): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40ee8fe0
```

Comment: Some code might be useful. Also, logs seem to be from standard email app. Is there any logs from Yours app available?

Comment: @sandrstar This is the problem , the previous logcat was taken from my app BUT i don't use any email thing, it just a simple layout and classes

Answer (score 0):

A simpler fix is to disable "Exchange Services" under Settings : Apps : All

(you may need to swipe over to see the "All" tab)